# Trying to script a button to post from Google Sheets to Discord

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, discord

Hi anyone that can help.

I have been trying to script a button that will post some data from a google sheet to as a discord message using a webhook but I am slowly losing my mind. By limited knowledge of scripting, I mean HTML and CSS way back in 2009.

The scenario is: each day has a column with 5 pieces of data (Sales, Buys, Refunds, Labour costs, Losses) for each day of the week, and would like to have a script attached to a button underneath that can be pressed to send this data when triggered. (I used to use Zapier for this but it would trigger every time there was an update to the cells). I have managed to send messages through to discord with the use of a button, but I can't figure out how to send the values of these cells in a simple update message. Here is the code I have been using to figure it out:

```
function saturdaypost() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange('D16:D22');
var message = range.getValue(); 

var discordUrl = "hidden";

`changed to var payload = {content:message} and received the new error` 
var payload = JSON.stringify({content: message});

var params = {
method: "POST",
payload: payload,
muteHttpExceptions : true,
contentType: "application/json"
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(discordUrl, params);
Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
```

Please could someone tell me where I am going wrong before I rip my own eyes out

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. unfortunately, I cannot understand `I have managed to send messages through to discord with the use of a button, but I can't figure out how to send the values of these cells in a simple update message.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and yor gorl?

Comment: I have used script to send a simple one line message of text to a discord server, but I am trying to send the values of 5 cells.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Maybe I can reword it: I cannot make my script send the value of 4 cells as a message to discord.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, for example, when you modify your script from `var message = range.getValue();` to `var message = range.getValues().flat().join(",");`, is that your expected result?

Comment: Hi, I managed to find out where my error was laying and why the correct data wasn't being held as the active sheet has 5 hidden sheets before it, it was looking in the first sheet rather than the needed one.